# dotenv не работает в node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Подключаю `.dotenv` файл который находится в той же директории.

```
require('dotenv').config({path:'/.dotenv'})
```

Выдает:

```
ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined.
```

Кодировку `utf-8` в параметры конфига указывал и все равно та же ошибка.

Comment: Вангую очень древнюю ноду

Comment: 10,19. Возможно ли что проблема именно в устаревшей версии?

Comment: TextEncoder появился в 11 версии ноды

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Буду пробовать обновить.